# supabase nextjs pagerouter problem while authantication

Tags: supabase, supabase-js

I am using supabase along with nextjs page router and i don't know how to set this thingand in middleware.ts there is an error  in "lib/database.types"i don't know about where to get it ,when i npm installed npm install @supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs @supabase/supabase-js this one lib folder was created

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using the App Router approach to setting up Supabase for your Next.js project. Please refer to this link for setting up Supabase on your Next.js project (with Pages router):

https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/nextjs-pages